# Why do the olympic beach volleyball teams not set?

Tags: technique, olympics, beach-volleyball

I have been watching a lot of the Olympic Beach VolleyBall, and I noticed that they almost never set the ball using an overhead set (two hands open position over their head.)

Has this type of set fallen out of favor, or become illegal?  What has changed?

Comment: Are you talking Mens or Womens?  I've watched a lot of Mens and they set all the time, but seems the women don't as much.

Comment: Womans mostly, but have watched mens also, just not the whole stream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has always been the case that overhand sets have been judged very strictly in beach volleyball. Players can and do make overhand sets - see for example, [a couple of points from the Rio Grand Slam earlier this year](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zdddU6JaGk#t=6m23s), but they have to come out *very* clean in order to avoid being called as a double touch.